# I'm running 32-bit Windows on an x86-64 PC. Should I download the 32-bit or 64-bit Python installer?

Tags: python, installation, download, 32bit-64bit

I have an Intel T9550 64-bit processor with 32-bit Windows Vista. I want to install Python 2.7.1 onto my PC. From the python.org website, which installer should I use:

- "Python 2.7.1 Windows Installer"?
- or "Python 2.7.1 Windows X86-64 Installer"?

The latter one is for x86-64. I don't understand if this bit refers to the processor or the OS.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: That explains it all! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Even though you have a 64-bit processor, your OS is of a 32-bit flavour. The Windows installer for Python targets the OS it is built on, not just the processor. Since your OS is 32-bit, you can only install the regular 32-bit Python 2.7.1 Windows installer.

Note that you can install both 32-bit (under a 32-bit emulation) and x86-64 flavours of Python installer had you have Windows 64-bit on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The first of the two Windows installers on the [download page](http://www.python.org/download/) are for 32-bit versions of the operating system.

The Windows *AMD64* / *Intel 64* / *X86-64* description refers to 64-bit versions of Windows.

Luckily, an installer for the other 64 bit version of windows - *IA64*,  or *Itanium* - 
is no longer available on the download page. See for example [2.5.4 downloads](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/):
"`For *Win64-Itanium* users: python-2.5.4.ia64.msi"